# XAMPP - allow internet connection

Tags: xampp

I usually do my web dev on a production server, now i need to bring some work at home. I have installed XAMPP on my laptop and it seems to work perfectly fine.

Most of my project involves CURL enabled, I need to make my xampp application to access the internet. Perhaps give it some IP address and Gateway.

I've seen documentation how to enable CURL on xampp, yet I'm struggling to find how to make XAMPP to have internet access.

I'm not asking how to access my XAMPP remotely, I'm simply asking how to give internet connection to xampp application for my CURL and other social network API to work.

Comment: Quick suggestion, you shouldn't connect XAMPP to the internet, for the default configuration gives very little protection against unauthorized users.

Answer (score 1):

Curl is just the library used to make HTTP requests. If your code is unable to access remote resources like social network APIs, I'd look at the firewall configuration of the operating system first. You have to make sure that the Apache server is able to make outgoing connections on port 80 and port 443 (for https requests)